# Angular how to get enum key (not as a string but as Enum type) from string value

Tags: typescript, enums

I would like to retrieve the key of the enum not as as a string but with enum.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-av8rkx

```
enum Widgets {
  Foo = "this is foo",
  Bar = "this is bar"
}

const current = "this is foo";
console.info(current); // 'this is foo';

let enumKey = Object.keys(Widgets)[Object.values(Widgets).indexOf(current)];
console.log(typeof(enumKey)) // here it returns string
```

I would like to access the enum using the above 'enumKey' ie.

```
Widgets[enumKey]
```

But this is not working for me. Can anyone help me how to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can build a "reverse" enum like this:

```
type Reverse<T extends Record<any, string>> = { [K in keyof T as T[K]]: K }
type ReverseWidgets = Reverse<typeof Widgets>
const ReverseWidgets: ReverseWidgets =
    Object.entries(Widgets)
        .reduce((o, [key, value]) => (o[value] = key, o), {} as any)

const current = "this is foo"
const enumKey = ReverseWidgets[current] // "Foo"
const next = Widgets[enumKey] // Widgets.Foo
```